# how do I design intermittent via points for travel itinerary

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

I am trying to design the backend and have the following use case.

I have flight information from point A to B and need to define a schema which supports different use cases.

I'm trying to find a good way to handle the case, when there are stopover via points.

For e.g. flight route for A -> B actually looks like this:

```
A -> C
C -> D
D -> B
```

so A -> B is one entity, but in turn, it is comprised of several legs.

My current design:

AirLeg table:

```
- id
- departure and arrival information
- viaPoints: BOOL
```

viaPoints table:

```
- id
- airLegId // FK into Airleg table
- similar departure and arrival information from airLeg table
```

// if viaPoints flag is True in AirLeg table, viaPoints table can be queried for, using airLegId table to retrieve intermediaries.

Is there a better way to deal with this ?

I thought I'll add the info I am storing about a one way trip or segment:

- AirLeg-id
- Departure Airport : FK into airports
- Arrival Airport : FK into airports
- Departure timestamp (in departure city's local time)
- Arrival timestamp (in arrival city's local time)
- flight duration of this airleg: static value
- flightId : FK into airlines yielding airline name and flight number
- Baggage Policy : text
- Misc (TEXT: Cancellation policy)

**EDIT:**

I added a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017881/how-do-i-design-return-travel-itinerary-vs-one-way-itinerary) and I think the answer to this problem will have to cater to both the requirements.

If there are multiple segments in a trip, price is defined for the complete trip and not individual segments

Similarly, the price for a round trip is specified as a unit and not individual components from A->B and back, B->A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd design it like this:

```
Journeys:

 - ID
 - Other info (billing, whatever)

Segments:

 - ID
 - JourneyID (FK)
 - departure, arrival, etc
```

And an additional view

```
Journeys_View

 - Journeys.*
 - First departure
 - Last arrival
```

Comment: I assume you work out the first and last segments for an journey by looking at the earliest segment (based on time?)

Comment: Yes. Using the ID would not be a good idea if you first select a middle segment and then chose the connecting segments - so the departure/arrival time in UTC is the order criterion

Comment: I am storing time in the city's local timezones. I have billing in a separate table. So, in my table, all I have is departure/arrival airport, time and flight info. Isn't then what you suggested similar to what I've posted in the question ?

Comment: @brainydexter, the design is different because every journey works the same - you always look for "segments", not just if there's a boolean flag set somewhere. This makes the design more self describing, and simplifies your SQL.

Comment: @NevilleK Thanks for clarifying. Also, please see the Edit I made in the question.

Comment: @NevilleK this was exactly what I meant. @brainydexter the `Journey`table will also link the journey to the traveller etc, so while it might carry not much info in itself, it will carry join information

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to piece together the two questions, and it's not totally clear what you want to do - but I think it boils down to the following.

You have an **itinerary**, which is the parent item. An "itinerary" has multiple legs (question: do you want to deal with multi-part itinerarys, e.g. "London->Paris->New York->London"?). An itinerary has a price. The price is NOT the sum of the price of the legs, because return trips are cheaper than two one ways.

```
Itinerary
---------
ID
Price

Leg
----
Departure Airport : FK into airports
Arrival Airport : FK into airports
Departure timestamp (in departure city's local time)
Arrival timestamp (in arrival city's local time)
flight duration of this airleg: static value
flightId : FK into airlines yielding airline name and flight number
Baggage Policy : text
Misc (TEXT: Cancellation policy)
```

You could store price in a separate table - but you only need to do this if price changes independently of itinerary (e.g. if the price on Monday is $100, and on Tuesday it's $200).

I would encourage you not to use "[magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)" in your database schema - instead of having the return leg be "-1", you should leave it NULL - there is no return leg. This makes your SQL a lot easier to read, and far less error prone - you don't depend on developers remembering that "-1" means there's no return leg, -2 meaning there's a provisionally booked leg etc.

Comment: I also have a multi-part itinerary as a use case. I need to support three type of itineraries: a) One-way b) Return trip c) multi-part. You're correct about the fact, that `itinerary` has a price, and not individual legs. I gathered a solution from different facts here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9018830/280924. Let me know what you think. Thanks..