# how do I design return travel itinerary vs one way itinerary

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, entity-relationship, erd

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem:

- Price for one-way trips is different than price for round trip itineraries.

In the backend, I have a table for storing the itinerary (which yields an id). I have another pricing table, which defines what is the price of this id from startDate to endDate.

My itinerary table can only represent information for one way travel. How do I model round trip itineraries ?

One way to deal with this was:

have another column in the table: returnId

if returnId = -1 -> one way trip
else
 returnId = id to its complimentary itinerary

for e.g.
A -> B is a roundtrip itinerary & C -> D is a one way trip;

It would look something like this:

```
Id    |    Departure    |    Arrival    |    ReturnId
1     |    A            |    B          |      3
2     |    C            |    D          |     -1
3     |    B            |    A          |      1
```

In this case pricing table

```
Id    |    StartDate    |    EndDate    |    Price
1     |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012|      150.00
3     |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012|      150.00
2     |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012|      100.00
```

I'd like to hear thoughts/suggestions on this design ?

**EDIT:**

I added a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017733/how-do-i-design-intermittent-via-points-for-travel-itinerary) and I think the answer to this problem will have to cater to both the requirements.

One thing, I'd like to mention is..the price for a round trip is specified as a unit and not individual components from A->B and back, B->A.

Similarly, if there are multiple segments in a trip, price is defined for the complete trip and not individual segments.

Comment: can you clarify the difference from your previous question please at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017881/how-do-i-design-return-travel-itinerary-vs-one-way-itinerary

Comment: @gbn you linked to this page itself ?

Comment: I mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017733/how-do-i-design-intermittent-via-points-for-travel-itinerary That is, are they duplicates?

Comment: They are not duplicates, but I think it will be worthwhile to link the two, since the solution I come up in either will have to support both the use cases.

Comment: @gbn Fixed. Added the link. I think I'll cross link that question here as well.

Comment: Your "itinerary" table appears to have two records with the same ID. Is the last row supposed to be ID 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blended the two answers and came up with this:

**Journey**:

- journeyId
- baggage policy
- misc

**Segment**:

- segmentId
- journeyId (FK)
- segment info

**Price**:

- journeyId
- startDate
- endDate
- price

Journey

```
Jid |   baggage             |   misc
1   |   "baggage policy1"   |   "round trip A->B"
2   |   "baggage policy2"   |   "one-way C->D"
3   |   "baggage policy3"   |   "one-way E->H with a hop in F, followed by G to H"
```

Segment

```
Id  |   Jid |   Dep |   Arrival
1   |   1   |   A   |   B
2   |   1   |   B   |   A
3   |   2   |   C   |   D
4   |   3   |   E   |   F
5   |   3   |   F   |   G
6   |   3   |   G   |   H
```

Price

```
JourneyId    |    StartDate    |    EndDate    |    Price
1            |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012|      150.00
3            |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012|      150.00
2            |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012|      100.00
```

Thoughts ?

Comment: I'd move the start/end dates onto the journey table, as they're not price related, and also add depart/arrive on the segment table...

Comment: shouldn't we use a view instead for start/end date, as suggested in the other answer ? Agreed, for adding depart/arrival date on segment table.

Comment: if you remove srart/end completely, and add depart/arrive to the segments then yes, you could do that.. Whether you use a view or not depends on how you'll be querying the data..

Comment: I'd be hooking up these with hibernate/java. I'm quite new to hibernate, so I'm not sure how I'll do that. But, yes, the idea will be to identify what is the start/end date and price for a journey.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding a self join like that, I would have a Trip table which contains the one-to-many mapping of Trip to Itinerary (where 1 trip consists of multiple itineraries). This way, a trip can have more than 2 legs..

Something like:

```
Trip_Itineraries
TripId     |   ItineraryId
1          |   1
1          |   2
2          |   3

Itinerary
ItineraryId    |   Departure    |    Arrival
1              |   A            |    B      
2              |   B            |    A      
3              |   C            |    D 

Pricing
ItineraryId    |    StartDate    |    EndDate       |    Price
1              |    Jan 1, 2012  |    Jul 10,2012   |    100.00
2              |    Jul 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012   |    100.00
2              |    Jul 1, 2012  |    Dec 10,2012   |    150.00
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT T.TripId, sum(P.price) 
FROM Trip_Itineraries T INNER JOIN Pricing P ON T.ItineraryId = P.ItineraryId
GROUP BY T.TripId
```

to get the total price for the trip..

Comment: Would this not return 200 for round trip of A -> B ?

Comment: From the link in that edit, I think I like the split: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9017790/280924. It's similar to what you suggested. I'll try to blend both of your replies and post an answer.

Comment: @brainydexter: I thought you were asking for individual prices per leg of the trip. If not then just make the key of the pricing table = TripId instead of ItineraryId. I would have suggested something similar to the linked answer, but I was assuming that you had an existing fixed Itinerary and Pricing table and had to work around them.. :-S

Comment: Thanks. I've put an answer below with what you suggested.